# Why doesn't set_value() work with foo[bar][x][lorem] array inputs?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So let's say i have a form where the user can add as many dogs as they want by pressing a `+` button.

The form is like:

```
Dog #1 <br/>
<input name="house[dogs][][name]" value="<?=set_value('house[dogs][0][name'])?>"/>
<input name="house[dogs][][age]" value="<?=set_value('house[dogs][0][age]')?>" />

Dog #2 <br/>
<input name="house[dogs][][name]" value="<?=set_value('house[dogs][1][name'])?>"/>
<input name="house[dogs][][age]" value="<?=set_value('house[dogs][1][age]')?>" />
```

On CodeIgniter, I run a form validation in order for `set_value()` to work as well:

```
$house = $this->input->post('house');
$dogs  = $house['dogs'];

$i = 0;
foreach($dogs AS $dog){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("house[dogs][$i][name]", 'Dog Name', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("house[dogs][$i][age]" , 'Dog Age' , 'required');
 $i++;
}
```

This whole thing doesn't work, How to make `set_value()` support array inputs like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to make the input `name` the exact same as the first parameter of `set_value()`.

One might not be able to be `[]`, while the other can use `[0]`.

Comment: I was a bit unclear on what you meant here, but now it makes sense and I think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Very related: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179581/ Ironically, a post I made months ago that was bumped this morning.

Also related: [CodeIgniter: Validate form with multidimensional POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117372/codeigniter-validate-form-with-multidimensional-post-data)

---

`<ignore>`

To make a long story short, Codeigniter does not handle indexed field names very well by default.

To simply repopulate the input and work around `set_value()`'s shortcomings, you can try something like this:

```
<?php
$value = isset($_POST['house']['dogs'][1]['age']) ?     // was the value posted?
         form_prep($_POST['house']['dogs'][1]['age']) : // if so, clean it
         '';                                            // if not, leave empty
?>
<input name="house[dogs][1][age]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
```

Since you're probably using a loop to output these, I don't think it will be too much of a bother. You could populate a separate array of values and read those instead if you wish, you get the idea. `set_value()` automatically runs `form_prep()`, so that's why I added it.

I'm not too sure about the validation. You may have to do the validation yourself, which while bothersome, shouldn't be too difficult. Remember you can always run the validation methods manually. Example:

```
if ($this->form_validation->valid_email($this->input->post('email')) {}
```

You may want to just take the easy way out and change your field names to use a single index, like `dog_age[]`, which I believe will make the validation easier for CI to handle. Best of luck, hoping for a fix one of these days in CI core.

`</ignore>`

---

**EDIT**: I have no idea how this escaped me, but apparently validation and set_value *should* in fact work as expected - not sure if this was a recent change or if the issue never really existed. I definitely remember having issues with it before, and the linked posts suggests others are too. Check out this answer though:

[CodeIgniter: Validate form with multidimensional POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117372/codeigniter-validate-form-with-multidimensional-post-data/6781506#6781506)

I tested it (running 2.0.2) and it does in fact work. I don't see anything in the [change log](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html), but I did test it and it did work. Make sure your on the latest version and try again perhaps, or let us know if I'm missing something here.

Like [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766245/why-doesnt-set-value-work-with-foobarxlorem-array-inputs/6766489#6766489) says, you probably just have to explicitly index the field names like `name="house[dogs][1][name]"` instead of `name="house[dogs][][name]"`.

Comment: What a coincidence, Thanks for the work around, i agree it's not the cleanest thing in the world, Sometimes CI puts me down :( the reason why i use array inputs is the fact that it's easy to import the whole info using something short like: `$this->input->post('info')`

Comment: Totally agree, I have the same feelings about this. Using multidimensional input names is quite handy. Appreciate the accept, but I'd leave this open for a while and see if anyone has something relevant to share. Besides, it's only been 45 minutes since you asked. Don't worry about letting questions float around a couple days until the night shift gets a chance to see them. :)

Comment: @Ryan: See above ^^^. I'm interested in a solution too - let's see if anyone has a better one.